# How do I create an instance of a Hadoop file system remotely using Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I want to access a Hadoop file system through Java remotely, but every time I run the following code it's just showing the Local file system.

I have gone through many solutions on Stack Overflow but nothing seems to work.

Here is a current attempt:

**Code**

```
Configuration obj = new Configuration();

obj.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020");
obj.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
obj.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

URI uri = new URI("hdfs://localhost:8020/");
Path path =new Path("/Myfiles/wc.txt");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(obj);

System.out.println(fs.getHomeDirectory());

if(fs instanceof DistributedFileSystem) {
    System.out.println("HDFS is the underlying filesystem");
} else {
    System.out.println("Other type of file system "+fs.getClass());
}

FSDataInputStream fsDataInputStream = fs.open(path);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fsDataInputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String line;
while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
bufferedReader .close();
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Post what code you have and the error you're seeing.

Comment: Make sure that appropriate `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml` files are present in the classpath of your application. Those files should contain a valid configuration of your  Hadoop cluster.

Comment: i have tried .you can see in code that i have posted above.

Comment: Are you running Hadoop on your local machine? Is file `/Myfiles/wc.txt` present on HDFS?

Comment: "/Myfiles/wc.txt " this file is stored on hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

This setting:

```
obj.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020");
```

is already present here: ( No sense to use it.)

```
obj.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
obj.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

These files, of course, are not available outside hadoop cluster. You have to copy them.

If your `fs.defaultFS` is `localhost:8020` this code will work only on the host where the name node is listening, no remotes.
it should be something like

```
obj.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://mycluster.local:8020"); ( MRv1 )
obj.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://mycluster.local:8020"); ( YARN )
```

where my cluster.local resolves to the correct ip address of the name node.

BTW best way to access HDFS from outside is webHDFS.